# More than 6 font sizes with different color codes

Tags: html, css

I am doing a test and I need to create a landing page. There are more than 6 different font sizes here. Here is the list:

Nav & footer links: 24px / 400 regular / Montserrat

Heading 1: 115px / 500 medium / Cormorant Garamond

Headings 2: 45px / 500 medium / Montserrat

Body text and dates: 20px / 400 regular / Montserrat

Heading 3: 110px / 500 medium / Cormorant Garamond

Buttons: 22px/ 500 medium / Montserrat

Footer headings: 30px / 500 medium / Montserrat

1. So since I could only use h1 to h6, should I mix two of similar sizes and make them six different sizes? Or I have another option that I am not aware of?

---

2. The other question I have is, since some of the smallest text (h6) are one color and somewhere else is another color, I tried to put the color codes like this:

   ```
   <h6 style="color:#4A455C;">MAR 9, 2019</h6>
   <h6 style="color:#FFFFFF;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</h6>
   ```

But I know it is not probably the most efficient way. What do you suggest?

Comment: What do you mean by “what are my options here?”

Comment: FYI, we are not taking the same test and have none of the context you do. Please explain your questions more thoroughly.

Comment: I mean, should I mix two of similar sizes and make them six different sizes? Or I have another option that I am not aware of?

Comment: @HereticMonkey I have updated my post.

Comment: `h1..h6` are for creating headings, not styling text to make it bigger. For styling, use CSS (not inline, but with selectors). https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Getting_started_with_the_web/CSS_basics

Comment: I still have no clue what you're talking about. "There are more than 6 different font sizes here." Yes, you have 7 listed. That is more than 6. "So since I could only use h1 to h6, should I mix two of similar sizes and make them six different sizes?" That tells me that you're trying to use headings to format body text, which is wrong. Use a `p` tag to format paragraph text.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to make different classes for font size and font color for example:

```
.font-xxl{
   font-size:40px;
}
.font-xl{
   font-size:30px;
}
.font-m{
   font-size:20px;
}
.font-s{
   font-size:10px;
}

.font-green{
   color:green;
}
.font-red{
       color:red;
}
```

and then, just use `<h1 class="font-xl font-red>Hello World </h1>`